# How can I locate the 3rd div using DOM Traversing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me with how I can locate the 3rd div inside my parent `nav-user-dd`
using Traversing the dom? My goal is to locate the `nav-user-ddli` and add a class it using Dom Traversing. Thanks

```css
.nav-user-ddli {
  background: yellow
}

.nav-user-ddli.addClass {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div id="btnNavUser" class="nav-user-dd">
  <div class="nav-user-img"></div>
  <div class="nav-user-name">John Doe</div>

  <div class="nav-user-ddli">
      <div id="btnLogoutF" class="nav-user-ddli-item">test</div>
      <div id="btnLogoutF" class="nav-user-ddli-item">
      <a href="#">test</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I click the btnNavUser it should add class on the 3rd div using DOM Traversing.

Comment: I assume the class won't always be `nav-user-ddli`? (Otherwise, why not just use that to select the element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by selecting the parent element with `getElementById`

```js
const btnNavUser = document.getElementById("btnNavUser")
```

then, traverse its children with `children` property

```js
const thirdChild = btnNavUser.children[2]
```

finally, add the desired class with

```js
thirdChild.classList.add("addClass")
```

```js
const btnNavUser = document.getElementById("btnNavUser")
const thirdChild = btnNavUser.children[2]
thirdChild.classList.add("addClass")
```

```css
.nav-user-ddli {
          background: yellow
        }

        .nav-user-ddli.addClass {
          background: green
        }
```

```html
<div id="btnNavUser" class="nav-user-dd">
          <div class="nav-user-img"></div>
          <div class="nav-user-name">John Doe</div>

          <div class="nav-user-ddli">
              <div id="btnLogoutF" class="nav-user-ddli-item">test</div>
              <div id="btnLogoutF" class="nav-user-ddli-item">
              <a href="#">test</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either directly with class name `nav-user-ddli` (?) or this selector
`.nav-user-dd>div:nth-child(3)`

```js
document.querySelector(".nav-user-dd>div:nth-child(3)").style.background = 'red'
```

```html
<div id="btnNavUser" class="nav-user-dd">
  <div class="nav-user-img"></div>
  <div class="nav-user-name">John Doe</div>

  <div class="nav-user-ddli">
      <div id="btnLogoutF" class="nav-user-ddli-item">test</div>
      <div id="btnLogoutF" class="nav-user-ddli-item">
      <a href="#">test</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```